# Is there a way to quickly navigate to previously visited directories

Tags: neovim, working-directory

I quickly want to switch between directories I previously visited without typing `:cd` and then the full pathname again and again. Is there a plugin or a way that can keep an account of the directories I visited during a vim session from which I can select and go to that directory instantly? I use neovim-qt on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a start at dirstack-like set of commands; you could place the following in (e.g.) `~/.vim/plugin/dirstack.vim`:

```
let g:dir_stack = []
command -complete=dir -nargs=1 -bang -bar Pushd
      \ call add(g:dir_stack, getcwd()) | execute 'cd<bang>' <q-args>
command -bang -bar Popd
      \ let dir = remove(g:dir_stack, -1) | execute 'cd<bang>' dir | unlet dir
command -bar Dirs echo g:dir_stack
```

I've paid no special attention to `:tcd`/`:lcd` (which should be doable, if you're brave enough), or to the special argument `-` (unecessary; `:Popd` == `:cd -`, except that `:Popd` won't save the last directory like `:cd -` will), or to `:Pushd` with no arguments (it's a shame that `:cd` behaves slightly differently on different platforms).

Comment: Nice. It would be nice to also have a directory selector and other options to support bash `pushd +1` and so on in order to quickly change the current directory for an already stacked one  (which becomes the new top of the stack)

Comment: @LucHermitte yeah there are definitely some missing features. Happy for anyone (me included) to build a plugin around it.

Comment: This got me inspired :)  https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/pushd.vim

Answer (score 1):

While in bash I overuse `pushd`/`popd` and even a [few other helpers on top on them](https://github.com/LucHermitte/Bash-scripts/blob/master/push.bashrc), I don't use a similar workflow in Vim.

I guess it's mostly because I do file management (`cp`, links, removing, running complex tests...) in the console while I just use vim to edit files (and compile, git add/commit/diff/blame...). When I need to open a file from another project I have plugins that offer navigation (based of ctags or on LSP). And for Vim I have a command dedicated to open anything from the `'runtimepath'`.

Once I'm in a buffer that belongs to a project, the current working directory is automatically set to the root directory of that said project (usually determined by where `.git/` is, but other mechanisms are available as well). I do that through  [a feature from my (central) library plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Project.md#312-auto-detect-the-project-root-path). And I never change manually the global current directory, not any local buffer directory.

Comment: Linux has so many useful pre-installed things. Wish they would have come pre-installed in Windows too. ;(

Comment: Oh... I am sorry! They do come pre-installed in Windows too. I was not aware of these commands. So, Thankyou! Also, D. Ben Knoble' s answer was sufficient for my work. I just added a command to quickly go to any index of dir_stack.

Comment: They are part of bash, and of a few other shells IIRC. Don't forget to update the stack top when you go to any directory indexed in the stack. Otherwise `:Popd` won't pop the current directory.